# enable form when clicking on it for register

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-core

I have a slider in top of my page in asp.net core .It has a form for registration. but I want to when user click on one of filed , slider stops and he can register easily
what do I do for it?

There are 2 different form with 2 slider, but it is important for me after clicking in one of filed , slider can not move for register

```
<section class="home-slider owl-carousel ">
    <div class="slider-item  ">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            <div class="row d-md-flex no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-end" data-scrollax-parent="true">
                <div class="one-third order-md-last img js-fullheight" style="background-image:url(images/bg_3.jpg);">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="one-forth d-flex js-fullheight align-items-center ftco-animate" data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '70%' }">
                    <div class="text mt-md-5">
                        <h1 class="mb-4">Ev yapımı yiyecekler <br> Delicious Foods</h1>
                       <!---- Order-->
                        <div class="booking">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row align-items-center">

                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <div class="booking-form">
                                            <form>
                                                <div class="control-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required" />
                                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-user"></i></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
                                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" required="required" />
                                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-mobile-alt"></i></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group date" id="date" data-target-input="nearest">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" placeholder="Date" data-target="#date" data-toggle="datetimepicker" />
                                                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group time" id="time" data-target-input="nearest">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" placeholder="Time" data-target="#time" data-toggle="datetimepicker" />
                                                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#time" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <select class="custom-select form-control">
                                                            <option selected>Guest</option>
                                                            <option value="1">1 Guest</option>
                                                            <option value="2">2 Guest</option>
                                                         
                                                            <option value="10">10 Guest</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <button class="btn custom-btn" type="submit">Order Now</button>
                                                    <!--<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-3 mt-3">Order Now</a></p>-->
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <!--End Order-->


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Java script code:

```
 $.Scrollax();

var carousel = function() {
    $('.home-slider').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    autoplay: true,
    margin:0,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    nav:true,
    dots: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: false,
    items: 1,
    navText : ["<span class='ion-ios-arrow-back'></span>","<span class='ion-ios-arrow-forward'></span>"],
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      600:{
        items:1
      },
      1000:{
        items:1
      }
    }
    });
    $('.carousel-testimony').owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        loop: true,
        items:1,
        margin: 30,
        stagePadding: 0,
        nav: false,
        navText: ['<span class="ion-ios-arrow-back">', '<span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward">'],
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items: 1
            },
            600:{
                items: 1
            },
            1000:{
                items: 1
            }
        }
    });
};
carousel();
```

and the other one :

```
    Navigation.prototype.draw = function() {
    var difference,
        settings = this._core.settings,
        disabled = this._core.items().length <= settings.items,
        index = this._core.relative(this._core.current()),
        loop = settings.loop || settings.rewind;

    this._controls.$relative.toggleClass('disabled', !settings.nav || disabled);

    if (settings.nav) {
        this._controls.$previous.toggleClass('disabled', !loop && index <= this._core.minimum(true));
        this._controls.$next.toggleClass('disabled', !loop && index >= this._core.maximum(true));
    }

    this._controls.$absolute.toggleClass('disabled', !settings.dots || disabled);

    if (settings.dots) {
        difference = this._pages.length - this._controls.$absolute.children().length;

        if (settings.dotsData && difference !== 0) {
            this._controls.$absolute.html(this._templates.join(''));
        } else if (difference > 0) {
            this._controls.$absolute.append(new Array(difference + 1).join(this._templates[0]));
        } else if (difference < 0) {
            this._controls.$absolute.children().slice(difference).remove();
        }

        this._controls.$absolute.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        this._controls.$absolute.children().eq($.inArray(this.current(), this._pages)).addClass('active');
    }
};
```

Comment: How’s your slider code defined? Add the event listener of focus and blur is the basic logic , you could provide more code of your attempts and debug details.

Comment: @FengzhiZhou Thanks for your answer, I don't know JavaScript, this is a template and I want to change on it . I update the question and add the JavaScript code, But as I said , I want to when I click on form , slider get stop

Comment: @FengzhiZhou  Thank you so much again for you help, would you mind if , I ask you take a look to the other my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77982533/how-can-i-use-date-picker-in-my-form-in-bootstarp?noredirect=1#comment137482254_77982533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a code sample to help you solve and understand the problem.

```
…
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //For testing clarity I comment this
        //$.Scrollax();

        // Event listeners for the page visibility change
        // This will help stop autoplay if you hide the browser page
        function handleVisibilityChange() {
            if (document.hidden) {
                $('.owl-carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
            } else {
                $('.owl-carousel').trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange, false);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var owl = $('.home-slider').owlCarousel({
                loop: true,
                autoplay: true,
                margin: 0,
                animateOut: 'fadeOut',
                animateIn: 'fadeIn',
                nav: true,
                dots: true,
                autoplayHoverPause: false,
                items: 1,
                navText: ["<span class='ion-ios-arrow-back'></span>", "<span class='ion-ios-arrow-forward'></span>"],
                responsive: {
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    600: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    1000: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                }
            });

            // Stop the carousel when any input gets focus
            $('.booking-form input, .booking-form select').on('focus', function () {
                owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
            });

            // Optional: Restart the carousel when the input loses focus
            $('.booking-form input, .booking-form select').on('blur', function () {
                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Now it will work as you expected.

Comment: Oh my good, it works. thanks so much , thanks alot , I add it after that javascript code and it s work