# How can I use Date Picker in my form in bootstarp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, datepicker, form-control

I want to use from date picker from a template
this is my field:

```
<div class="form-group">
<h4 class="card-title">Material Date picker</h4>
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label class="m-t-20">Default Material Date Picker</label>
<input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2017-06-04" id="mdate">
<label class="m-t-40">Default Material Date Timepicker</label>
<input type="text" id="date-format" class="form-control" placeholder="Saturday 24 June 2017 - 21:44">
</div>
</div>
 </div>
```

and this is Java script  code. I don't know about Java script code. but in template is written , "Use .bootstrapMaterialDatePicker to create it.
"
But I don't know where?

part of Java script code:

```
(function($) {
"use strict"


// MAterial Date picker
$('#mdate').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    weekStart: 0,
    time: false
});
$('#timepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    format: 'HH:mm',
    time: true,
    date: false``
});
$('#date-format').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    format: 'dddd DD MMMM YYYY - HH:mm'
});

$('#min-date').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
    minDate: new Date()
});
// Clock pickers
$('#single-input').clockpicker({
    placement: 'bottom',
    align: 'left',
    autoclose: true,
    'default': 'now'
```

I see this error in consol:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker is not a function
at form-pickers-init.js:6:17
at form-pickers-init.js:108:3
```

Comment: `bootstrapMaterialDatePicker` seems to indicate Material UI or something not JUST bootstrap perhaps?  Also your JavaScript code is malformed as posted

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I write  part of java script code, but I dont know where can I user the class: bootstrapMaterialDatePicker ,

Comment: You should edit your question to add clarity and proper code.  So you basically copied this code from somewhere without understanding the use perhaps? (which is NOT a reason to NOT post properly formed code) Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
 Perhaps update with where you copied it FROM or some other information - OR look how that source utilized other libraries/code and not just Bootstrap - also update with a tag for the bootstrap version

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes I copied the code, because i dont know java script , so I need help to solve this issue then I can use date picker, this is a web template that has given to me

Comment: If it is actually bootstrap's date picker, it should be `$(...).bootstrap.MaterialDatePicker`. However, I couldn't not find a reference to a bootstrap datepicker. I've had to use a 3rd party library (apart from bootstrap) in the past in order to get the desired UI that I wanted in the past, and I don't think bootstrap has one.

Comment: @Shmack it is 1 3th library, It is a admin panel template that I want to use it on my project, but for use it , it says:Use .bootstrapMaterialDatePicker to create it. But I dont know where I had . I see the  Java script code and the code for input , but how can I use it , where I had to use and change?

Comment: @Shmack actually "bootstrapMaterialDatePicker " does not call any where in my code, where can I add it in my form I don't know it

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss   actually "bootstrapMaterialDatePicker " does not call any where in my code, where can I add it in my form I don't know it

Comment: have you call the package on your layout by defining the plugging path or using CDN

Comment: @MohamedRaza   yes under the page both js and all CSS, I dont need to call it in my code in the question?

Comment: Per your question: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker is not a function
at form-pickers-init.js:6:17
at form-pickers-init.js:108:3`, notice it says "bootstrapMaterial...", not "bootstrap.Material...". Also, notice where the error is being thrown; lines 6 and 108.

Comment: the error occurs because the module `bootstrapMaterialDatePicker` is not initiated. you have to import the packages and you should define it globally

Comment: @MohamedRaza I have the java script code that I wrote in question , and I link the file path to to page , now what do I do ? where part of code I had to chaneg?

Comment: inside the `<head>` tag you have to place the css styles and js files of `bootstrapMaterialDatePicker ` . please edit the question with `bootstrapMaterialDatePicker  documentation you have used`

Comment: @MohamedRaza That is my problem, all files are placed in the file and <head> but it dose not show

Comment: please share the code as well on the question so we can identify the way to resolve your problem

Comment: @MohamedRaza it is shared, the part of code that , if I click on it it had to show date picker, and then the java script code , That I have been shared on question too, which code do you need more? and I link the file on tag head too